# Flash drive file system is different depending on device?

Tags: linux, windows, usb-flash-drive, kali-linux, liveusb

I have a Samsung 64 GB USB 3.1 flash drive, that was previously used as a Kali Linux Live OS. Recently, it has been formatted to exFAT, and it is used to hold all my personal files for projects and such. When I plug it into a Windows machine, it shows all my files normally. But, if I plug it into my Chromebook laptop, with ChromeOS (Linux) on it, it shows all the files that were used in the Kali Linux Live OS, as if they still existed and were active on the flash drive, and my personal files are nowhere to be found. I would like to be able to access my files on my Chromebook.

Can someone tell me why/how this happening, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drive has more than one partition, created when making the Kali live installer. Some data is on one, some on another.

Simply open the USB flash drive in a disk management program such as *diskmgmt.msc* in Windows or *gparted* in Linux and combine the partitions. If you don't mind wiping all data, it's easiest to remove *all* partitions, making it all free space, then formatting the drive.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this when I get home.

Comment: Alright, so, I loaded up GParted, and it still shows only one partition. However, that one partition was listed as 'Kali Linux Live'. I already took everything off the flash drive, so I just reformatted the whole thing anyway. I put my files back on it and put it into my Chromebook, and it stopped showing all the Kali Linux Live files. Thanks.